# Use a connection string in a package

Tags: c#, nuget

Is it possible to use a connection string from a nuget package?  I am working on an internal package and would like to use the connection string from the App.config instead of having each project include the connection string.

Comment: At least you can pull connection string as param. I definetly sure that you can read config file from your package.

Comment: I can read the string from the web.config in the project. but not the config file in the package

Answer (score 0):

*ConfigurationManager* uses *.config* file from executable project. If you want read info from file which is not in your project you can’t use *ConfigurationManager*.
You can transform projects *.config* file and this values will be accessible by *ConfigurationManager*, see links

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/source-and-config-file-transformations
https://haacked.com/archive/2010/11/19/nuget-transformation.aspx